# Varargs with null parameters in Java

Tags: java, variadic-functions

The following code simply uses a null reference as a varargs parameter.

```
package currenttime;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    private static void temp(String...str)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        temp(null,null);
        temp(null);
    }
}
```

The first call to the method `temp(null, null);` displays `[null, null]` means that `str[0]=null` and `str[1]=null`.

but the later call to `temp(null);` causes the `NullPointerException` to be thrown which appears that the `str` itself is `null`.

If it's type cast to `String` something like this `temp((String)null);`, it works and displays `[null]`.

Why in the last call, an explicit type cast is required? *It seems to me that it's considered to be a string array with a `null` reference which is different from the first call.* What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It seems to me that it's considered to be a string array with a null
>   reference which is different from the first call

Exactly. This is what happening.

Actually, it's just about `precedence` between: - `exact-match`, `var-args`, `boxing` and `type-casting`.

Compiler follow the following precedence when checking for methods to be called, or how the argument will be passed: -

> Exact-Match > Type-Cast > Boxing > Var-args

So, you can see that, `var-args` has the lowest precedence, and `exact-match` has the highest precedence. That means, if an `argument` is `good-enough` for an `exact-match` then it will be considered as such.

Now, when you pass `null` as an argument, then `null` can directly be passed to your `var-args` parameter as the `value of reference`. It is an `exact match` for the parameter.
So, you need to `typecast` it explicitly to `String` to tell that its actually the first element of your `var-args` parameter

Whereas, in case of `null, null`, it will be taken as `two` elements of your `var-args`. As it cannot be a `value of reference`.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(str);` constructs a `java.util.List` with a `null` entry in it. `String str = null;` has whatsoever nothing to do with the reference of the `List` being created (which is not `null`).