# Java, Arrays to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to check if my array has a given element or not. For this, I am converting that array to list and then using contains. But, I am getting this strange behavior.

```
 int[] arr = null;
 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).contains(1));  //output as false
 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(null).contains(1)); //nullPointerException
```

Why the first one is not throwing NPE? Please suggest.

Comment: The first is a list with one element, a null value, type of `List<int[]>`. The second is trying to build a list (`List<Object>`) from the varargs array, but the array is null and causes NPE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Varargs with null parameters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870021/varargs-with-null-parameters-in-java)

Comment: bug locked [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4189641) already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive represent value and object variable represent reference.
null is a keyword in java and it is used to denote absence of something or reference of nothing.
If you create object like

```
Object obj=new Object();   or   Integer i=new Integer();
```

Heap memory assign some space for reference variable obj and i.
when you assign obj=null; or i=null; this means obj and i will not point to that memory or any of it.

```
int[] arr=null;
```

Here arr is a primitive variable,and its value is null.

When you try to convert array to list by Arrays.asList(arr) your passing empty array but your passing.

Because

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

asList() method take varargs array and return list.

When you write

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList (arr).contains(1)); //output as false
```

means your actually comparing 1 from the returned list and contains(1) method check whether the 1 is present or not in list.

But in second statement `System.out.println(Arrays.asList (null).contains(1));`
 your passing null.
asList(null) method try to

```
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
```

that means return statement calling to

```
ArrayList(E[] array) {
        if (array==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
    a = array;
}
```

and in second statement you pass null.

In case,   `Integer[] arr = null;` your actually creating object of Integer wrapper class and object variable represent reference, here arr is object and it is referring to null.And null means reference of nothing.So, that's the reason why  `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(null).contains(1));` throw NPE

About null in java you can visit this link for more details :
[9 Things about Null in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/12/9-things-about-null-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java primitive types do not work with [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-); this is masked because of the array (which is a valid type `T`, so a `List` of `int[]`). You want the corresponding wrapper type. Something like,

```
Integer[] arr = { 1 };
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).contains(1));
```

which outputs (as expected)

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of `Arrays.asList()` method is : Check [Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Arrays.java)

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... array) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(array);
}
```

That's why, you cannot contract like `new ArrayList<int>()` with primitive datatype `int`.

If so, if you change your source `int` to `Integer`

```
Integer[] arr = null;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList (arr).contains(1)); ///nullPointerException
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(null).contains(1)); //nullPointerException
```